# ¿Cómo se mantienen los íconos e imágenes usados luego de compilar en Java?

Tags: java, java-swing

Lo que quiero es, luego de compilar el jar, que las imágenes que use se mantengan, tanto los íconos como cualquier otra imagen que puse en la GUI.

Por ejemplo:

```
frame.setIconImage(new ImageIcon("src/main/java/Images/Icon_Title.png").getImage());
```

A la hora de probar el programa sí se ven los íconos, pero a la hora de compilar dejan de verse dichos íconos, y si pongo una carpeta con la dirección `src/main/java/Images` en el lugar donde tenga el `.jar` y pongo ahí las imágenes, sí se efectúan los `setIcon`.

Estuve investigando y vi que recomiendan usar `getClass.getResourceAsStream()` para así al compilar no haya necesidad de poner la carpeta con imágenes fuera del jar.

Y por más que traté de usarlo, siempre me daba un `null` y esto hace caerse el programa.

También traté de agregar la carpeta con su dirección dentro del `jar` y tampoco funciona de esta manera.

**Estructura:**

```
src.main.java
           │
           ├─images
           │    └──Icon_Title.png
           │
           └─view
                └──MainGUI.java
```

**Actual `setIcon`**

```
this.setIconImage(new ImageIcon("src/main/java/images/Icon_Title.png").getImage());
```

Pero para evitar tener que usar una carpeta de imagines externa al `.jar` **(al compilar)** quiero usar algo tal:

```
this.setIconImage(new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/images/Icon_Title.png")).getImage());
```

Comment: Explora las posibilidades de getResource y getResourceAsStream para referenciar recursos dentro del JAR. relacionada:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593154/get-a-resource-using-getresource

Comment: Ya había revisado esa pregunta previamente y la verdad quede igual.

La GUI se encuentra en `/src/main/java/View/Main.java` y la imagen que trato de cargar en `/src/main/java/Images/Icon_Title.png`

Comment: ¿Cuál IDE usas?

Comment: Actualmente NetBeans 12.3

Comment: ¿En qué package esta tu punto de entrada (`public static void main(String[] args)`)?

Comment: Se encuentra en el package `view`

Comment: Logré solucionando copiando la carpeta "src" en la carpeta "dist", donde está el ejecutable. Espero le sirva.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En Netbeans:

1. Verifica la inclusión del archivo.
   En *Project Properties > Sources > Includes/Excludes* revisa que el archivo de la imagen se encuentre en *Included Files*.
2. Verifica la copia del archivo para construcción.
   Si la imagen se incluye, después de hacer un *Build* deberás poder ver en *Window > Files* en la carpeta *<Aplicación>/build/classes/<RutaDeLaImagen>* una copia del archivo.
3. Verifica que no se excluya del jar.
   Revisa que en *Project Properties > Build > Packaging > Exclude From JAR File* no exista una expresión que abarque al archivo de la imagen. Al descomprimir el jar generado debe encontrarse la copia del imagen.
4. Al llamar a `getResource()` asegúrate de colocar la ruta completa del "paquete" de la imágen iniciando con `/`.

```
this.setIconImage(new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/images/Icon_Title.png")).getImage());
```

Comment: Por alguna razón ahora si funciona, puse las imagines manualmente en la carpeta classes y esta ves lo logra tomar, lo que no entiendo es por que antes no las tomaba, de todas formas gracias @Sal. Por cierto la pestaña `includes/excludes` no me sale y tampoco alguna opción en la pestaña de `Build`. Supongo que investigare un poco el tema, en que forma hace el build NetBeans, para así añadir la carpeta al build.

Comment: Aquí [enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9752972/how-to-add-an-extra-source-directory-for-maven-to-compile-and-include-in-the-bui) encontré la forma de añadir una carpeta al build a la hora de compilar

Answer (score 0):

Ten en cuenta que el getResource carga desde el inicio del classpath, en tu caso, probablemente desde src/main/java. He hecho un ejemplo así un poco simple, pero cargando desde esta estructura de paquetes:

[image: estructura paquetes ejemplo]

Haciendo esta referencia en codigo:

```
InputStream imagen = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/org/prueba/mainer/Images/image.gif");
```

Carga el fichero tanto desde eclipse:

[image: consola en eclipse]

Como desde el JAR en cmd

[image: desde cmd]

Por cierto, por estándar los nombres de los paquetes no deben empezar por (ni tener) mayúsculas.

Comment: La verdad no se que estoy haciendo mal, trate de hacerlo tal cual tu ejemplo y me sigue retornando `null`

Comment: Comparte si quieres la estructura de paquetes exacta y lo que has hecho en el código, por si al verlo vemos algo más.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya añadí la información que me solicitaste. 
No puse todo los paquetes que tiene el proyecto, dado que no veo necesario ya que lo único que estoy utilizando en este caso es el paquete `images` y `view`.