# ¿Como poner ruta para que recursos carguen en el build? JAVA

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ant

Hola estoy haciendo un proyecto java en el cual ocupo acceder a varios archivos y imágenes al momento de hacer determinada acción en el programa, el problema es que en el entorno de desarrollo si me funciona, pero cuando lo paso al build me deja de funcionar por los path.
Mi pregunta es ¿Cual es la manera correcta de poner las rutas de **archivos** e **imagenes** en Java para que funcione tanto en el entorno de desarrollo como en el ejecutable?.
De momento yo estaba poniendo como **path** la carpeta src pero que se esta mal ya que no me funciona en el build.

esta es una imagen a la que deseo acceder por ejemplo:
Img/Reports/boleto.png

tambien deseo acceder a "src/Reports/boletoPoliza.jrxml"

¿Cual seria la forma de acceder a ellas tambien en el build?

Comment: Revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/469697/cómo-se-mantienen-los-%C3%ADconos-e-imágenes-usados-luego-de-compilar-en-java/470542#470542).

Comment: con build, creo que te refieres a que usas ant para compilar... podrías confirmar?

Comment: @RuslanLópez si te soy sincero no se si uso ant soy un programador novato en Java, pero a lo que me refiero con build es cuando lo compilo y hago el ejectuable(.jar) desde netbeans que es donde lo "compilo"

Comment: si el tipo de proyecto tiene su icono de taza naranja es ant (que es le más común), si tiene la taza naranja con una m es maven, son los dos más comunes

Comment: Ya mire, estoy usando ant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El "nombre del proyecto" y `"src"` no existe a la hora de crear un ejecutable `JAR`, puedes comprobarlo tu mismo, creando el ejecutable y extrayendo todo en el escritorio, solo aparecen tus paquetes y clases que hallas creado.

Digamos que quiero un `ImageIcon` y la ruta esta en `"/icons/myimage.png"`

```
private static ImageIcon getImageIcon(String path) {
    return new ImageIcon(Icons.class.getResource(path));
}
```

O si quiero un `Image`

```
ImageIO.read(Icons.class.getResource(path));
```

El `Icons.class` se puede remplazar por un `getClass()` si no estas en un método estático.

El proyecto se vería algo así

```
controllers
icons
  - myimage.png
main
model
view
  - Icons.java
```

Esas 2 maneras de cargar imágenes me están funcionando actualmente en el `IDE` y en el `JAR`.

Comment: Aclaro que estoy utilizando ``Eclipse`` y ``Linux`` y no se si otros entornos de desarrollo construyen el ``JAR`` de otra manera, ademas de si influye en las rutas el ``File.separator`` del sistema, pueden probarlo en Windows a ver si les funciona.