# problema con el jasperreport al generar el .jar

Tags: netbeans

Hola amigos del foro he aquí nuevamente molestando, tengo un problema que cuando genero el .jar no me muestra los reportes, pero en netbeans ningún problema, este el código que se esta utilizando:

```
private void cmdimprimirActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    int desicion = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "¿Desea imprimir esta Cotización de Repuestos?");
    switch (desicion) {
        case JOptionPane.YES_OPTION:
            try {
                MyConnection cn = new MyConnection();
                Connection conn = cn.getConnection();
                JasperReport reporte = null;
                String path = "src\\Archivos_Consorcio\\cotizacion.jasper";
                Map parametros = new HashMap();
                parametros.put("siniestro", txtsiniestro.getText());
                reporte = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObjectFromFile(path);
                JasperPrint jprint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reporte, parametros, conn);
                JasperViewer view = new JasperViewer(jprint, false);
                view.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                view.setVisible(true);
            } catch (JRException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Frmcoticonsorcio.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            break;
        case JOptionPane.NO_OPTION:
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No imprimir");
            break;
    }
}
```

estos son los import que se utiliza:

```
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader;
import net.sf.jasperreports.view.JasperViewer;
```

he seguido todos los consejos e incluso elimine todas las librerías y volví a cargarlas y nada, porque se genera este error, debe ser un error de código no lo creo, porque anteriormente me funcionaba bien y ahora nada, sino no he cambiado nada, favor de ayudarme

Comment: El archivo .jasper lo debes obtener como un *recurso*; guíate de [ésta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/469697/cómo-se-mantienen-los-%C3%ADconos-e-imágenes-usados-luego-de-compilar-en-java/470542#470542), sólo cambia `.png` por `.jasper`.

Comment: Muchas gracias @sal por tu respuesta y te comento que solucione el problema al crear el .jar ahora puedo ver los reportes hechos en jasperrpot, y es este es la solución. en la línea reporte = hay que cambiarlo de esta manera "reporte = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(getClass().getResource("/Archivos_Consorcio/cotizacion.jasper"));", además en la línea de String path hay que cambiarlo de esta manera "String path = "src/Archivos_Consorcio/cotizacion.jasper";". Por otro lado les comento que se puede trabajar a través de Netbeans o hacerlo en .jar y funcionan ambos