# "Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.toString()" because the return value of "java.lang.Class.getResource(String)" is null" - Netbeans (JAR)

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

tengo un problema pendiente de años sin poder solucionar con respecto a la ejecución de un pequeño proyecto (de escritorio) hecho en java con NetBeans. La generación del archivo `.jar` y su posterior ejecución con el archivo `.bat` me genera el siguiente mensaje de error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Vale decir que, el programa ejecuta sin problemas desde el IDE. A continuación, les mostraré la estructura general del proyecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Come ven, al archivo a ejecutar (main) es el **MenuMD.java**, que es el que llama a las demás ventanas que se encuentran dentro de la carpeta **Interfaz** a través del botón **Programas**.

El siguiente código pertenece a **MenuMD.java**:

```
package Interfaz;

import ClaseFondo.ImagenFondo;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class MenuMD extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public MenuMD() {
           
    initComponents();
    
    //Permite cambiar el icono de ventana
    setIconImage(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Iconos/IconoMD.jpg")).getImage());
    
    //Se invoca a la clase fondo, para implementarla en el escritorio...
    escritorioMD.setBorder(new ImagenFondo());
    
    //Permite maximizar el formulario
    this.setExtendedState(MenuMD.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">//GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
private void initComponents() {

    escritorioMD = new javax.swing.JDesktopPane();
    menuherraMD = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
    menuprog = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    jSeparator1 = new javax.swing.JPopupMenu.Separator();
    jSeparator2 = new javax.swing.JPopupMenu.Separator();
    menuinfnum = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    jSeparator3 = new javax.swing.JPopupMenu.Separator();
    menunumpri = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    jSeparator4 = new javax.swing.JPopupMenu.Separator();
    progmcdmcm = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    jSeparator5 = new javax.swing.JPopupMenu.Separator();
    menuecudio = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    jSeparator6 = new javax.swing.JPopupMenu.Separator();
    menusalir = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    menucred = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    menudatos = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    escritorioMD.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 204, 204));

    javax.swing.GroupLayout escritorioMDLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(escritorioMD);
    escritorioMD.setLayout(escritorioMDLayout);
    escritorioMDLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        escritorioMDLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 744, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    escritorioMDLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        escritorioMDLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 221, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    menuprog.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Iconos/System.png"))); // NOI18N
    menuprog.setText("Programas");
    menuprog.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            menuprogActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    menuprog.add(jSeparator1);
    menuprog.add(jSeparator2);

    menuinfnum.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Iconos/Search.png"))); // NOI18N
    menuinfnum.setText("Info Número");
    menuinfnum.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            menuinfnumActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    menuprog.add(menuinfnum);
    menuprog.add(jSeparator3);

    menunumpri.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Iconos/Undo.png"))); // NOI18N
    menunumpri.setText("Generar Num. Primos");
    menunumpri.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            menunumpriActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    menuprog.add(menunumpri);
    menuprog.add(jSeparator4);

    progmcdmcm.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Iconos/Tip.png"))); // NOI18N
    progmcdmcm.setText("MCD y MCM");
    progmcdmcm.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            progmcdmcmActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    menuprog.add(progmcdmcm);
    menuprog.add(jSeparator5);

    menuecudio.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Iconos/Stationery.png"))); // NOI18N
    menuecudio.setText("Ecuaciones Diofánticas");
    menuecudio.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            menuecudioActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    menuprog.add(menuecudio);
    menuprog.add(jSeparator6);

    menusalir.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Iconos/Close.png"))); // NOI18N
    menusalir.setText("Salir");
    menusalir.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            menusalirActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    menuprog.add(menusalir);

    menuherraMD.add(menuprog);

    menucred.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Iconos/user.png"))); // NOI18N
    menucred.setText("Crédito");
    menucred.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            menucredActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    menudatos.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Iconos/Info.png"))); // NOI18N
    menudatos.setText("Datos del Programa");
    menudatos.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            menudatosActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    menucred.add(menudatos);

    menuherraMD.add(menucred);

    setJMenuBar(menuherraMD);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(escritorioMD)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(escritorioMD)
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>//GEN-END:initComponents

private void menucredActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_menucredActionPerformed
  
}//GEN-LAST:event_menucredActionPerformed

private void menudatosActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_menudatosActionPerformed
    Crédito cred = new Crédito();
    escritorioMD.add(cred);
    cred.setVisible(true);
}//GEN-LAST:event_menudatosActionPerformed

private void menuprogActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_menuprogActionPerformed
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}//GEN-LAST:event_menuprogActionPerformed

private void menusalirActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_menusalirActionPerformed
    System.exit(0);
}//GEN-LAST:event_menusalirActionPerformed

private void menuecudioActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_menuecudioActionPerformed
    Diofanto dio=new Diofanto();
    escritorioMD.add(dio);
    dio.setVisible(true);
}//GEN-LAST:event_menuecudioActionPerformed

private void progmcdmcmActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_progmcdmcmActionPerformed
    McdMcm mm = new McdMcm();
    escritorioMD.add(mm);
    mm.setVisible(true);
}//GEN-LAST:event_progmcdmcmActionPerformed

private void menunumpriActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_menunumpriActionPerformed
    GenNumPrim gnp = new GenNumPrim();
    escritorioMD.add(gnp);
    gnp.setVisible(true);
}//GEN-LAST:event_menunumpriActionPerformed

private void menuinfnumActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_menuinfnumActionPerformed
    NatNum inf = new NatNum();
    escritorioMD.add(inf);
    inf.setVisible(true);
}//GEN-LAST:event_menuinfnumActionPerformed

public static void main(String args[]) {
           
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
       
        public void run() {
            new MenuMD().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
    
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify//GEN-BEGIN:variables
private javax.swing.JDesktopPane escritorioMD;
private javax.swing.JPopupMenu.Separator jSeparator1;
private javax.swing.JPopupMenu.Separator jSeparator2;
private javax.swing.JPopupMenu.Separator jSeparator3;
private javax.swing.JPopupMenu.Separator jSeparator4;
private javax.swing.JPopupMenu.Separator jSeparator5;
private javax.swing.JPopupMenu.Separator jSeparator6;
private javax.swing.JMenu menucred;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem menudatos;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem menuecudio;
private javax.swing.JMenuBar menuherraMD;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem menuinfnum;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem menunumpri;
private javax.swing.JMenu menuprog;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem menusalir;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem progmcdmcm;
// End of variables declaration//GEN-END:variables
}
```

Creánme que he intentado de todas las formas posibles con información de la red y con casos parecidos expuestos en esta plataforma, pero sin éxito. No sé cómo ni dónde aplicar la obtención de la ruta de los recursos que la ejecución del **.jar** menciona al ejecutarlo.

Sería de mucha ayuda, puesto que, me permitiría cerrar y completar este proyecto que tengo pendiente desde la universidad.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Revisa [ésta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/469697/cómo-se-mantienen-los-%C3%ADconos-e-imágenes-usados-luego-de-compilar-en-java/470542#470542) y coméntanos.

Answer (score 0):

No encuentra la imagen porque no está en la direccion que espesificas en el código. Al momento de generar el .jar del proyecto, asegurate de que esté dentro de la carpeta que contenga "Iconos". Cuando generes el .bat hazlo dentro de la misma carpeta principal y luego puedes enviar el acceso directo al escritorio.

En mi caso cuando genero el .jar, lo guardo dentro de la carpeta dist que es una de las carpetas que se generan cuando abres un proyecto en netbeans y tambien donde se guarda el .jar. Dentro de dist creo el .bat y envio el acceso directo al escritorio, asegurandome de que todas las librerias y demás componentes que uso dentro del código tambien estén en la carpeta.
Espero y te ayude. Saludos.